# PDO Statement not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE deleted = ? LIMIT ?, ?");
$query->bindValue("1", 0);
$query->bindValue("2", 2);
$query->bindValue("3", 5);
    try{
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Unfortunately this returns a result with no rows (but an empty result not even an error), and when I run this sql query through phpmyadmin, it fetches me multiple rows. 
Any suggestions would be really be helpful. I can't get through this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo

Comment: Have you configured PDO to throw exceptions? It doesn't by default.

Comment: This worked. And this was so stupid I wasted 2 hours. :\ Thanks mate.

Comment: please try to close the question, either by picking a suitable answer or writing your own answer and selecting it as the answer

Comment: I will have to wait 2 days to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First comment to this question helped me very well: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058463/pdo-statement-not-returning-result?noredirect=1#comment35234247_23058463)

And solved my problem. Al the above suggestions mentioned above were previously tried and did not work.

Answer (score -1):

bindValue expects an integer in case of you using a question mark as a binder
and not a string like you provided:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE deleted = ? LIMIT ?, ?");
$query->bindValue(1, 0);
$query->bindValue(2, 2);
$query->bindValue(2, 5);
    try{
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
}
```

or simply do this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE deleted = ? LIMIT ?, ?");
$binds = array(0,2,5);
    try{
        $query->execute($binds);
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Defensively right, edited added an explanation for him.

Comment: Instead of solving, both your variants will actually fail in default emulation mode.

Answer (score -1):

try to use like this

```
<?php
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE deleted = :deleted LIMIT :limit, :offset");
$query->bindValue(":deleted", 0);
$query->bindValue(":limit", 2);
$query->bindValue(":offset", 5);
    try{
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: why should he try it?

Comment: but **what** should it fix? what is the problem this code is fixing?